# Laravel : Different json output for the same query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel application where the route "/phones/brand/{brand_id}" returns all the phones associated with that brand. This works perfectly except with brands other than brand_id 1, the output is different.

**/phones/brand/1 result**

```
[{"id":1,"phone_model_id":1,"model":"Iphone 5"},
{"id":2,"phone_model_id":1,"model":"Iphone 5s"},
{"id":3,"phone_model_id":1,"model":"Iphone 6"}]
```

**/phones/brand/2 result**

```
{"3":{"id":6,"phone_model_id":2,"model":"galaxyy s3"}}
```

I am unable to work with this data as it returns empty slots in javascript.

Console log:

```
Object [ <3 empty slots>, Object ]  script.js:84:11
```

Here is also the code for the controller action for that endpoint.

```
public function showByBrand($brand)
{

return Phone::all()->where('phone_model_id', '=', $brand);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Phone::where('phone_model_id', '=', $brand)->get(['id', 'model', 'phone_model_id'])->toJson();`?

Comment: @PatrykWoziński Yes, it still returns the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Using `->all()` will immediately return all records. You want to use your `->where()` method followed by `->get()` to then retrieve those filtered records.

Try this:

```
public function showByBrand($brand)
{

return Phone::where('phone_model_id', '=', $brand)->get();

}
```